# What is the complexity of copying a bitset? Is it the same as that for a bit mask?

Tags: c++, bitmask

I intend to know about the differences in performance or a bit mask as compared to bitset. I know copying a bitmask will take O(1) as it is basically represented just as an integer, so is that the same for bitsets as well, where each value is represented by 1 bit, hence making it the same size as a bitmask? Or will copying a bitset take O(N) time.

I'm trying to measure the usefuleness of bitmasking, specifically in the context of competitive programming.

Thanks!

Comment: afaik, bitmasking is simply a technique, so you manipulate individual bits.  It is NOT necessary to be always just an integer.  For example, you may use a `char[]` and make use of bitmasking technique to represent `length * 8` bits, for which copying that can still be `O(n)`.  If you are restricting yourself to 64 (or 32, or whatever acording to your architecture) or less bits, then it is actually meaningless to discuss the big-O.

Comment: There's A LOT of variables that go into this. What architecture, what compiler, what optimization level, etc. Really the only way you can check is profile it yourself.

Comment: @mascoj: Asymptotic complexity is not really affected by compiler, optimization, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about `std::bitset` or a bitset member of a class?

Comment: @DietrichEpp If you are asking about performance, complexity goes out the window when the compiler can decide how its implemented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a bitmask isn't constant-time. It's `O(n)` in the number of bits, just like any other operation that has to touch every element of a structure once.

Generally speaking, a C++ `bitset` object should behave comparably to a hand-rolled integer bitmask. For instance, operations on a `bitset<32>` should perform identically to the equivalent bitwise operations on a `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that something is **O**(*N*), you are talking about its *asymptotic complexity.*  "Asymptotic" is an important word here.  It means you are saying that the actual complexity of the thing *approaches* some linear function of *N* as *N increases without bound.*

So, it's important to know what *N* is.  In the case of a bit-mapped set, it's probably the number of unique elements that can be in (or not in) the set.  But what is *N* when you are talking about a data structure that fits in an `int`?  How can *N* increase without bound in that case?

It doesn't make any sense to talk about the asymptotic complexity of a thing if the thing doesn't *scale.*  An `int` does not scale.  An `int` is just an `int`.  It doesn't make any sense to say that an operation on an `int` is **O**(1) or **O**(*anythingelse*) for that matter.